# If I upgrade my version of Windows Vista, which version of Windows 7 will I get?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade, license

I need to get a laptop with Vista Home Premium onto a domain, which requires Business or Ultimate.  The computer, with Home Premium, is already registered for the free Windows 7 upgrade.  If I upgrade the Vista version now via Microsoft's 'anytime upgrades', will the Windows 7 upgrade allow me to maintain the same class of service, or will it be a home version, forcing me to buy another upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will only get Windows 7 Home Premium edition out of the free upgrade.

You will then need to do the anytime upgrade to Windows 7 Professional to be able to join it to a domain.

Comment: Hmm yeah, the free upgrade is tied to the OEM key that you got with the laptop.  So... if you were to buy a Vista-Vista upgrade, you would get a separate key (which would then not be eligible for the free upgrade).

Comment: Dell does have an W7 upgradeable version of Vista Home Pre., so I'm not out of luck, just out an extra $41.

Answer (score 1):

You need Windows Vista Business in order to upgrade to Windows 7 Professional.  See the following list for all paths:

```
* Windows Vista Home Premium -> Windows 7 Home Premium
* Windows Vista Business     -> Windows 7 Professional
* Windows Vista Ultimate     -> Windows 7 Ultimate
```